# Burn code to Attiny13/85 the easy way

Tags: attiny85, attiny13

Totally newbie here. I need to burn 50 blank Attiny13 chips with the following code:

https://github.com/mstratman/relay-bypass/blob/main/relay-bypass/relay-bypass.ino

AFAIK the code can be used by anyone since its license is MIT (https://mas-effects.com/relay.pdf)

What do you think is the easiest and quickest way to burn that code to my chips?

I have a Windows PC, an Arduino Uno, and USBASP, a chip socket, and the 50 chips. Never used arduino before. I do have a MiniPro TL866 programmer which is very easy to use, just upload the bin file, select the chip and click burn... Not sure if it would work with Attiny chips. If there is any hardware that would be easier/quicker to do the job I would buy it though.

Thank you!

Comment: start by determining if the programmer is capable of programming the chips

Comment: is your chip socket ZIF? If not, I would wait until I got one of those.

Comment: Is this spam, John Mayland 22? A simple yes or no.

Comment: This isn't a reasonable question here, asking if some unknown hardware could be better than the hardware you mentioned sounds to me like you are promoting the mentioned hardware.